# C++, How can a Base class include a child class as a member and call its methods

Tags: c++, inheritance, recursion

I have some experience with Java and C, but only now starting with C++.
I am trying to write a kind of logical tree :

All items derive from an abstract base class "**Item**".
Some items are containers and can contain several items. They derive from class "**Block**". A block can contain other blocks (this is recursive).
It also has an operator information
Other elements are runnables, they don't contain other items.

So far I could build my tree (and incidentally reflect it into/from an xml file using pugixml lib).
But now in my application, I would like to easily "move myself" along the tree.
The issue is that I need to keep a pointer to the container in which an item is stored, so i can move back. (very first block will have 'nullptr')

so I have : (of course there are #ifdef guardblocks that I don't copy here)

in item.h :

```
#include "block.h" //issue here!

enum Item_t { ... };

class Item
{
public:
    Item(Block* parentBlock, int order_number, int loop_number=1);
    virtual ~Item();

    virtual Item_t getItemSubClass() const = 0; //just for some kind of reflexivity hack for other function (here in this sample to show this is abstract)

protected:
    Block* m_parentBlock;
    int m_order_number;
    int m_loop_number;
    int m_current_loop=0;
private:
};
```

and in block.h :

```
#include "item.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

enum Operator { undefined, serial, parallel };

//class Item; // <= forward declaration ? won't work !

typedef std::map<int, Item*>::const_iterator item_iterator_t;

class Block : public Item
{
public:
    Block(Block* parentBlock, int order_number,  std::string op_str, int loop_number=1);
    virtual ~Block();

    void addSubItem(int index, Item* item);
    const Item* getSubItem(int index) const;

    item_iterator_t item_begin() const;
    item_iterator_t item_end() const;

    Operator getOperator(void) const;
    virtual Item_t getItemSubClass() const override;
protected:
private:
    Operator m_op;
    std::map<int, Item*> m_subItems;
};
```

Issue here :

- Item needs to include block.h, as it has member pointer to it, AND its constructor in cpp file calls block.addSubItem() method.
- Block obviously needs to include item.h as it derives from it.
- forward declaration is not enough when needing to call a method or inherit from a class (so for both cases).
- I could slightly change the design, by not setting parent/child relation into the constructor (this would work fine, but i'm interesting in seeing a solution to this inheritance/recursion issue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I was writing my question I found out a solution.
My problem was due to my coding style, where I tend to have my class.cpp files only include my corresponding class.h file, and centralize all other include command in the header. (finally it is maybe not a good practice)

- in block.h : (no other choice to inherit)

  ```
  #include "item.h"
  ```
- in item.h : use forward declaration

  ```
  class SeqBlock;
  ```
- in item.cpp : include both !

  ```
  #include "item.h" //optional as included in block.h but make it clear
  #include "block.h"
  ```

(not sure however this is the best solution or if the original design has a big flaw)

Comment: Without really looking into your code: This seems the right way to go. Normally the rule is: Include in the header file only what is really necessary, use forward declaration where possible. Include the remaining stuff from the implementation file (.cpp) only. Reduces dependencies and speeds up compile time (in larger projects).

Comment: So I was doing this in the opposite (and wrong!) way. I would now have to correct all my headers, and as this project will tend to be large, I will follow your advice, thanks !

Comment: In that case another recommendation: Always include the corresponding header file first in the implementation file. This way you'll get compiler errors soon if the header file is not "self sufficient".

Comment: Followed your recommendation and corrected all header/source files according to it. I accept my own answer since this is the only one i got so far, but will keep an eye on the topic if other answer arises.